# Multiple get methods Python google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, rest, get

Is it possible to have multiple GETs in a class in python?

i tried this:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler ):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write("test")

    def get(self, name, surname):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('N: %s S: %s' % (name , surname))   

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/.*', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

but doesn't work.

how should i do this? two different files with handling the two different paths?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have two methods named the same thing in *any* Python class.

Instead, what you should do is define two different classes, then use different URL pattern matches to choose which is used, rather than sending everything (`/.*`) to a single class.

Here's a (very) basic example:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write("test")

class NamePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, name, surname):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('N: %s S: %s' % (name , surname))   

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/(.+)/(.+)', NamePage), # Matches /foo/bar
        ('/.*', MainPage), # Matches everything else
    ], debug=True)
```

Comment: so this is like having 2 diffrent files, right?
how should i map them in the yaml file?

Comment: No, this can all go in a single file.

Comment: fine, but what about the mapping in the yaml?

Comment: Nothing in the yaml needs to change. Your existing Python file just needs to be updated to look like the above. See for example here: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/handlingforms.html

Comment: Or, you could have one class with one get method that has optional arguments. Which makes more sense depends on the nature of the requests.

Comment: @NickJohnson, how might you use 'optional arguments' in a get method?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to attempt here is overloading .
A more subtle approach at it rather than creating classes can be as follows:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler ):

    def get(self, name="default_name", surname="default_surname"):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('N: %s S: %s' % (name , surname))   

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/.*', MainPage)],debug=True)
```

Here name and surname are optional keywords arguments (They were positional arguments in your question). I hope it helps